# Trying to display the username of a member on a profile member area

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display a very simple username on a member page. I have searched here on stackoverflow but using what I found didn't worked.

I use the very common Registration/Login script from HTML Form Guide which uses 
fg_membersite.php and some other files. (login.php , register.php and so on).

When a user registers he chooses a Username, his Full name, email, and password.

while I try to display the full name (FullUserName) and the user email (UserEmail) 
**it works great**. I am using this:

```
<?= $fgmembersite->UserEmail(); ?>
<?= $fgmembersite->UserFullName(); ?>
```

But when I try to display the user name (UserName) it gives nothing. (the page showns up, but I basically get Welcome      ! , instead of Welcome {UserName}

I tried adding this to the fg_membersite.php file:

```
function UserName()
    {
        return isset($_SESSION['name_of_user'])?$_SESSION['username_of_user']:'';
    }
```

and this:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
       $_SESSION['username_of_user']  = $row['username'];
```

These two were already in the file:

```
$_SESSION['name_of_user']  = $row['name'];
$_SESSION['email_of_user'] = $row['email'];
```

While for the member page I trying with:

```
<?= $fgmembersite->UserName(); ?>
<? echo $_SESSION[ "username"]; ?>
<? var_dump($_SESSION[ "username"]); ?>
```

**My question is, is there a solution for this?**

Here is how I have it in the member page:

```
<?PHP
require_once("./include/membersite_config.php");

if(!$fgmembersite->CheckLogin())
{
    $fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("login.php");
    exit;
}

?>


 <li>Welcome <? echo $_SESSION['username_of_user']; ?>!
  <li class="active"><span class="pull-right"><a href='change-pwd.php'>Change password</a></span></li>
</ol>
 <span class="text-primary"><b></b></span>
```

**SOLVED:**

I just had to add "username" to this:

```
 $qry = "Select name, email from $this->tablename where username='$username' and password='$pwdmd5' and confirmcode='y'";
```

Like this:

```
$qry = "Select username, name, email from $this->tablename where username='$username' and password='$pwdmd5' and confirmcode='y'";
```

**Thank you everyone!!!**

Comment: can you show the code in order please? How you have in the file ?

Comment: Is there anything in $row['username'] ??

Comment: Need to check your whole script then, as your session is not getting set.

Comment: You can check the whole code here: http://pastebin.com/h7zJeZfL

Answer (score 1):

Should it not be this:

```
function UserName()
    {
        return isset($_SESSION['username_of_user'])?$_SESSION['username_of_user']:'';
    }
```

...and if it still returns nothing, the session variable is not set (did you session_start()?), dump the whole array out to check with:

```
echo "<pre>".print_r($_SESSION,true)."</pre>";
```

Here's your problem:

```
$qry = "Select name, email from $this->tablename where username='$username' and password='$pwdmd5' and confirmcode='y'";
```

You're not selecting the username from the DB!

Or try this (line 381 from the pastebin):

```
$_SESSION['username_of_user']  = $username;
```

Comment: It gives me this:Array
(
    [username_of_user] => 
    [name_of_user] => John
    [email_of_user] => .......@gmail.com
    [usr_87601d2e30] => ID2504
)

Comment: so your username session variable is indeed not set, the plot thickens... I think we need to see the whole script really.

Comment: the storage is in $_SESSION['username_of_user'] while the function posted originally checks $_SESSION['name_of_user']

Comment: there is a difference between the full Name: Name Surname , and the Username, I suppose

Comment: doesn't work with $_SESSION['username_of_user']  = $username; :/

Answer (score 0):

Is it should be like ??:-

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
       $_SESSION['username_of_user']  = $row['username'];

function UserName()
    {
        return isset($_SESSION['name_of_user'])?$_SESSION['username_of_user']:'';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a typo in your code:

```
function UserName()
{
    return isset($_SESSION['name_of_user'])?$_SESSION['name_of_user']:'';
}
```

Comment: this is the OP's code  - "isset($_SESSION['name_of_user'])?$_SESSION['username_of_user']"